# Trouble working with and updating dictionary using a class and function in Python 3 [Newbie]

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, dictionary, methods

I am somewhat new to coding.  I have been self teaching myself for the past year or so.  I am trying to build a more solid foundation and am trying to create very simple programs. I created a class and am trying to add 'pets' to a dictionary that can hold multiple 'pets'.  I have tried changing up the code so many different ways, but nothing is working.  Here is what I have so far.

```
# Created class
class Animal:

# Class Attribute
classes = 'mammal'
breed = 'breed'

# Initializer/Instance Attribrutes
def __init__ (self, species, name, breed):
    self.species = species
    self.name = name
    self.breed = breed

# To get different/multiple user input
@classmethod
def from_input(cls):
    return cls(
            input('Species: '),
            input('Name: '),
            input('Breed: ')
            )

# Dictionary
pets = {}

# Function to add pet to dictionary
def createpet():
    for _ in range(10):
        pets.update = Animal.from_input()
        if pets.name in pets:
            raise ValueError('duplicate ID')

# Calling the function
createpet()
```

I have tried to change it to a list and use the 'append' tool and that didn't work.  I am sure there is a lot wrong with this code, but I am not even sure what to do anymore.  I have looked into the 'collections' module, but couldn't understand it well enough to know if that would help or not.  What I am looking for is where I can run the 'createpet()' function and each time add in a new pet with the species, name, and breed.  I have looked into the sqlite3 and wonder if that might be a better option.  If it would be, where would I go to learn and better understand the module (aka good beginner tutorials).  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(First of all, you have to check for a duplicate **before** you add it to the dictionary.)
The way you add items to a dictionary `x` is

```
x[y] = z
```

This sets the value with the key `y` equal to `z` or, if there is no key with that name, creates a new key `y` with the value `z`.
Updated code:
(I defined this as a classmethod because the `from_input` method is one as well and from what I understand of this, this will keep things working when it comes to inheriting classes, for further information you might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172163/why-use-classmethod-instead-of-staticmethod?noredirect=1))

```
@classmethod
def createpet(cls):
    pet = cls.from_input()
    if pet.name in cls.pets:
        raise ValueError("duplicate ID")
    else:
        cls.pets[pet.name] = pet
```